# How to add all awaits ViewModel to Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task

How to add this three awaits in a Task.WhenAll() but with a return value of my model, cause without adding it in a WhenAll() I can get the return of my model. But when adding it in Task.WhenAll() all I get is some AsyncState, id properties.

```
var _pending = await _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Pending);
var _cancel = await _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Cancel);
var _completed = await _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Completed);

List<Task> taskList = List<Task<StatusLookup>>();
taskList.Add(_lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Pending));
taskList.Add(_lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Cancel));
taskList.Add(_lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Completed));

var result = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Thank you

Comment: please show your attempted solution to the problem

Comment: @Jason - Hi I included my attempted implementation with my original post.

Comment: have you checked the `Result` of each `Task` in `taskList`?

Comment: Yes, but it does not give the Model, but some Task properties instead.

Comment: What is the type of the `_lookupService`? What is the type of the `_pending`, `_cancel` and `_completed` variables?

Comment: _lookupService is an Interface with a task methods implementing. So when I assigned it directly to the var _pending the return value is the StatusLookupModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the results after `WhenAll` returns. You can use either `await` (calling it again on a completed task doesn't do anything) or read it out of `Result`.

```
var pendingTask = _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Pending);
var cancelTask = _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Cancel);
var completedTask = _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Completed);

await Task.WhenAll( new [] { pendingTask, cancelTask, completedTask } );

_pending = pendingTask.Result;
_cancel = cancelTask.Result;
_complete = completedTask.Result;
```

You might even be able to skip the `WhenAll`. This will give you a slightly different behavior but it would probably work just as well:

```
var pendingTask = _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Pending);
var cancelTask = _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Cancel);
var completedTask = _lookupService.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync<StatusLookup>(x => x.Code == LookupConstants.Completed);

_pending = await pendingTask;
_cancel = await cancelTask;
_complete = await completedTask;
```

Comment: Thank you John Wu, though question does Task.WhenAll don't need the "await" part?

Comment: Is an `await` missing before `Task.WhenAll`? Also awaiting the tasks one-by-one has the significant disadvantage that in case of an exception it might result in leaking fire-and-forget tasks. The `await Task.WhenAll` ensures that all started operations will be awaited.

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer here: https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/using-async-await-and-task-whenall-to-improve-the-overall-speed-of-your-c-code/

To tell it in the least possible words, you should assign tasks (without `await`) to variables. Then wait for them with `WhenAll` and finally read their results in their `Result` property.